# Retouching several images in several Task

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, executorservice, multitasking

## Generalities : explanations about my program and its functioning

I am working on a photo-retouching JavaFX application. The final user can load several images. When he clicks on the button REVERSE, a `Task` is launched for each image using an `Executor`. Each of these `Task` executes the reversal algorithm : it fills an `ArrayBlockingQueue<Pixel>` (using `add` method).

When the final user clicks on the button REVERSE, as I said, these `Task` are launched. But just after these statements, I tell the JavaFX Application Thread to draw the `Pixel` of the `ArrayBlockingQueue<Pixel>` (using `remove` method).

Thus, there are parallelism and concurrency (solved by the `ArrayBlockingQueue<Pixel>`) between the JavaFX Application Thread and the `Task`, and between the `Task` themselves.

To draw the `Pixel` of the `ArrayBlockingQueue<Pixel>`, the JavaFX Application Thread starts an `AnimationTimer`. The latter contains the previously-mentionned `remove` method. This `AnimationTimer` is started for each image.
I think you're wondering yourself how this `AnimationTimer` can know to what image belongs the `Pixel` it has removed ? In fact, each `Pixel` has an attribute `writable_image` that specifies the image to what it belongs.

---

## My problems

Tell me if I'm wrong, **but my program should work**. Indeed :

1. My JavaFX Application Thread is the only thread that change the GUI (and it's required in JavaFX) : the `Task` just do the calculations.
2. There is not concurrency, thanks to the `BlockingQueue` I use (in particular, there isn't possibility of draining).
3. The `AnimationTimer` knows to what image belongs each `Pixel`.

**However, it's (obviously !) not the case** (otherwise I wouldn't have created this question haha !).

My problem is that my JavaFX Application **freezes** (first problem), after having drawn **only some reversed pixels** (not all the pixels). On **the last** loaded image moreover (third problem).

---

## A detail that could be the problems' cause

But I would need your opinion.

The `AnimationTimer` of course doesn't draw the reversed pixels of each image directly : this is animated. The final user can see each pixel of an image being reversed, little by little. It's very practical in other algorithms as the creation of a circle, because the user can "look" how the algorithm works.

But to do that, the `AnimationTimer` needs to read a variable called `max`. This variable is modified (writen) in... each `Task`. But it's an `AtomicLong`. So **IF I AM NOT WRONG**, there isn't any problem of concurrency between the `Task` themselves, or between the JavaFX Application Thread and these `Task`.

However, it could be the problem : indeed, the `max`'s value could be 2000 in `Task` n°1 (= in image n°1), and 59 in `Task` n°2 (= in image n°2). The problem is the `AnimationTimer` must use 2000 for the image n°1, and 59 for the n°2. But if the `Task` n°1 et n°2 have finished, the only value known by the `AnimationTimer` would be 59...

---

## Sources

### When the user clicks on the button REVERSE

We launch the several `Task` and start several *times* the `AnimationTimer`. CLASS : RightPane.java

```
WritableImage current_writable_image;
for(int i = 0; i < this.gui.getArrayListImageViewsImpacted().size(); i++) {
    current_writable_image = (WritableImage) this.gui.getArrayListImageViewsImpacted().get(i).getImage();
    this.gui.getGraphicEngine().executor.execute(this.gui.getGraphicEngine().createTask(current_writable_image));
}

for(int i = 0; i < this.gui.getArrayListImageViewsImpacted().size(); i++) {
    current_writable_image = (WritableImage) this.gui.getArrayListImageViewsImpacted().get(i).getImage();
    this.gui.getImageAnimation().setWritableImage(current_writable_image);
    this.gui.getImageAnimation().startAnimation();
}
```

The `Task` are part of the CLASS GraphicEngine, which contains an `Executor` :

```
public final Executor executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(runnable -> {
    Thread t = new Thread(runnable);
    t.setDaemon(true);
    return t ;
});

public Task createTask(WritableImage writable_image) {
    int image_width = (int) writable_image.getWidth(), image_height = (int) writable_image.getHeight();
    Task ret = new Task() {
        protected Void call() {
            switch(operation_to_do) {
                case "reverse" :
                    gui.getImageAnimation().setMax(image_width*image_height); // USE OF "MAX" VARIABLE
                    reverseImg(writable_image);
                    break;
            }

            return null;
        }
    };
    return ret;
}
```

The same CLASS, GraphicEngine, also contains the reversal algorithm :

```
private void reverseImg(WritableImage writable_image) {
    int image_width = (int) writable_image.getWidth(), image_height = (int) writable_image.getHeight();
    BlockingQueue<Pixel> updates = gui.getUpdates();
    PixelReader pixel_reader = writable_image.getPixelReader();

    double[] rgb_reversed;
    for (int x = 0; x < image_width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < image_height; y++) {
            rgb_reversed = PhotoRetouchingFormulas.reverse(pixel_reader.getColor(x, y).getRed(), pixel_reader.getColor(x, y).getGreen(), pixel_reader.getColor(x, y).getBlue());
            updates.add(new Pixel(x, y, Color.color(rgb_reversed[0], rgb_reversed[1], rgb_reversed[2], pixel_reader.getColor(x, y).getOpacity()), writable_image));
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, here is the code of the CLASS `AnimationTimer`. There is nothing particular. Note the variable `max` is used here too (and in the CLASS `GraphicEngine` : `setMax`).

```
public class ImageAnimation extends AnimationTimer {
private Gui gui;
private AtomicLong max, speed, max_delay;
private long count, start;
private WritableImage writable_image;

ImageAnimation (Gui gui) {
    this.gui = gui;
    this.count = 0;
    this.start = -1;
    this.max = new AtomicLong(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    this.max_delay = new AtomicLong(999_000_000);
    this.speed = new AtomicLong(this.max_delay.get());
}

public void setMax(long max) {
    this.max.set(max);
}
public void setSpeed(long speed) { this.speed.set(speed); }
public double getMaxDelay() { return this.max_delay.get(); }

@Override
public void handle(long timestamp) {
    if (start < 0) {
        start = timestamp ;
        return ;
    }

    ArrayList<Pixel> list_sorted_pixels = new ArrayList<>();
    BlockingQueue<Pixel> updates = this.gui.getUpdates();
    for(Pixel new_pixel : updates) {
        if(new_pixel.getWritableImage() == writable_image) {
            list_sorted_pixels.add(new_pixel);
        }
    }

    while (list_sorted_pixels.size() > 0 && timestamp - start > (count * this.speed.get()) / (writable_image.getWidth()) && !updates.isEmpty()) {
        Pixel update = list_sorted_pixels.remove(0);
        updates.remove(update);
        count++;

        if (update.getX() >= 0 && update.getY() >= 0) {
            writable_image.getPixelWriter().setColor(update.getX(), update.getY(), update.getColor());
        }
    }


    if (count >= max.get()) {
        this.count = 0;
        this.start = -1;
        this.max.set(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        stop();
    }
}


public void setWritableImage(WritableImage writable_image) { this.writable_image = writable_image; }
public void startAnimation() {
    this.start();
}
}
```